# Flutter: Array of TextEditingController

Tags: flutter

What is the best way to set an array of `TextEditingController` in a flutter . I mean I need to get a value array of `Textfield`(1 to n) value and sent to the server.

Can anyone help how to achieve this?

I tried

```
for(int i=1;i<75;i++) { 
TextEditingController _controller[i] = TextEditingController(); 
}
```

Regards,
Sathish

Comment: dont get your question. A TextEditingController can only handle one FormField at a time as far as i know. But if you could provide code of what you have done so far... this would help...

Comment: for(int i=1;i<75;i++) {
TextEditingController _controller[i] = TextEditingController();
}

Comment: If you just want for getting value then I suggest creating array of value and store value on onChanged of Textfield

Comment: i want to validate all textfield and how to achieve it. validator is not in TextField thats the issue i am facing.

Comment: Did you mean validate when typing `_controller[i].addListener((){ // validate })`? or `TextFormField` with `valdiate` callback?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to do that

```
List<TextEditingController> _controller = List.generate(74, (i) => TextEditingController());
```

or

```
List<TextEditingController> _controller = [];
for (int i = 1; i < 75; i++) _controller.add(TextEditingController());
```

or

```
List<TextEditingController> _controller = [
  for (int i = 1; i < 75; i++)
    TextEditingController()
];
```

Comment: Thanks igor very much

Comment: how to add different value in each index in textediting controller as like [1,2,3,4,] etc not just number anything different

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can use this solution:

define list of map:

```
List<Map<String, TextEditingController>> get foodAccompaniments;
```

add new item when you need to get values :

```
foodAccompaniments.add({
  'name':TextEditingController(),
  'price':TextEditingController(),
});
```

and finally use controllers:

```
controller: foodAccompaniments.last['name'],

controller: foodAccompaniments.last['price'],
```

Answer (score 0):

**You have to add a list of *TextEditingController* and need to add the contoller text to that list and parse it as you need.**

```
  List<String> selection = [];  
 List<Product> productList = []; 

 //---------Adding contoller to list   
  
 productProvider.getAll(user.guid).forEach((element) {//---List<Product>
 final TextEditingController quantityController = 
 TextEditingController(text: element.quantity);
 quantityControllers.add(quantityController);
 });

   //-------Adding list of products to list
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> productItems = [];
   List<Product> productOriginalList = 
   productProvider.getAll(user.guid);
   for (int i = 0; i < productOriginalList.length; i++) {
   final Product product = productOriginalList[i];
   if (selection.contains(product.equipmentId)) {
               
   productItems.add(product.toJson(quantityControllers[i].text));
              }

 /* Map<String, dynamic> toJson(String quan) => {
'ProductId': id,
'Quantity': quan,
 };     
TextField(
controller: quantityControllers[index],*/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a dynamic widgets you can use -

```
TextEditingController _controller = new  TextEditingController();
```

inside your dynamic widget.This will automatically create new textediting controller evertime your widget runs. and at last you can store that value in your list.

Example :-

```
List <String>controllers = [];
controllers.add(_controller.text.toString)
```