# Flutter: keep data in textfield after setstate

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart, textfield, setstate

1. I have an array of textfields.
2. A button which adds a new textfield to the array.
3. If you add data to the textfield and add a new element by clicking the add button, the data added is gone.
4. The button function has a setstate in there to see the new elements to the array.
5. How can I add new elements to the array keeping the old data in the textfields?

start_workout.dart

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fultter_ultralifestyle/src/models/models.dart' show SetModel;
import 'package:fultter_ultralifestyle/src/presentation/widgets/dynamic_widget.dart';

class WorkoutStartScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String routeName = "workoutStart";
  @override
  _WorkoutStartScreenState createState() => _WorkoutStartScreenState();
}

class _WorkoutStartScreenState extends State<WorkoutStartScreen> {
  final List<SetModel> sets = [
  ];

  void _addSet() {
    final id = sets.length;
    sets.add(SetModel(id: id, pounds: 0, reps: 0));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Workout tracker"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: sets.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return DynamicWidget(
                      set: sets[index],
                      pos: index +1,
                      delete: () {
                        sets.removeAt(index);
                        setState(() {});
                      },
                    );
                  }),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => _addSet(),
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

dynamic_widget.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:fultter_ultralifestyle/src/models/models.dart';
import 'package:fultter_ultralifestyle/src/presentation/widgets/text_widget.dart';

class DynamicWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController poundsController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController repsController = TextEditingController();

  final SetModel set;
  final int pos;
  Function delete;

  DynamicWidget({
    Key key,
    @required this.set,
    @required this.pos,
    @required this.delete,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: text(
                  caption: "SET $pos",
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 20.0),
              Container(
                width: size.width / 4,
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    TextField(
                      controller: poundsController,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      inputFormatters: [
                        WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 10),
                    text(caption: "pounds".toUpperCase()),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 20,
              ),
              text(caption: "X"),
              SizedBox(
                width: 20,
              ),
              Container(
                width: size.width / 4,
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    TextField(
                      controller: repsController,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      inputFormatters: [
                        WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 10),
                    text(caption: "reps".toUpperCase()),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 5.0),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.delete_forever),
                onPressed: delete,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this just by making your `SetModel` update when the text changes in your text field. The main parts are the `updatePounds` and `updateReps` methods as well as the `onChanged` methods in the text fields in the dynamic widget.

I also made sure to initialize the controllers with the values contained in the `SetModel` when the dynamic widget is built.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: WorkoutStartScreen(),
  ));
}

class SetModel {
  final int id;
  int pounds;
  int reps;

  SetModel({
    this.id,
    this.pounds,
    this.reps,
  });

  void updatePounds(int pounds) {
    this.pounds = pounds;
  }

  void updateReps(int reps) {
    this.reps = reps;
  }
}

class WorkoutStartScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String routeName = "workoutStart";
  @override
  _WorkoutStartScreenState createState() => _WorkoutStartScreenState();
}

class _WorkoutStartScreenState extends State<WorkoutStartScreen> {
  final List<SetModel> sets = [];

  void _addSet() {
    final id = sets.length;
    setState(() {
      sets.add(SetModel(id: id, pounds: 0, reps: 0));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Workout tracker"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: sets.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return DynamicWidget(
                    set: sets[index],
                    pos: index + 1,
                    delete: () {
                      setState(() {
                        sets.removeAt(index);
                      });
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => _addSet(),
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DynamicWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController poundsController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController repsController = TextEditingController();

  final SetModel set;
  final int pos;
  final Function delete;

  DynamicWidget({
    Key key,
    @required this.set,
    @required this.pos,
    @required this.delete,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    if (set.pounds != 0) {
      poundsController.text = set.pounds.toString();
    }

    if (set.reps != 0) {
      repsController.text = set.reps.toString();
    }

    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: Text(
                  "SET $pos",
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 20.0),
              Container(
                width: size.width / 4,
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    TextField(
                      controller: poundsController,
                      onChanged: (String pounds) {
                        set.updatePounds(int.parse(pounds));
                      },
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      inputFormatters: [WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 10),
                    Text("pounds".toUpperCase()),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 20,
              ),
              Text("X"),
              SizedBox(
                width: 20,
              ),
              Container(
                width: size.width / 4,
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    TextField(
                      controller: repsController,
                      onChanged: (String reps) {
                        set.updateReps(int.parse(reps));
                      },
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      inputFormatters: [WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 10),
                    Text("reps".toUpperCase()),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 5.0),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.delete_forever),
                onPressed: delete,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Basically, the dynamic widgets are being redrawn every time you call `setState` from its parent. Since you never told the dynamic widgets to save anything, they are redrawn from scratch. This is still happening, except now we give them some initial information.

[Here](https://i.imgur.com/oVyYB70.mp4) is a video of it working.

Comment: Yep! If this is the solution for you, feel free to mark it as such

Comment: How can I do that? I tried to give u a positive or something like that but I don't know how

Answer (score 3):

Use controller!

```
TextEditingController password = new TextEditingController();

TextFormField(
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return "Could not be empty";
                    }
                    return null;
                  },

                  enabled: !isLoading,
                  controller: password,
                  obscureText: hidePassword,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    suffix: IconButton(icon: Icon((hidePassword)?Icons.remove_red_eye:Icons.cancel),onPressed: () => setState(() => hidePassword = !hidePassword),),
                      labelText: "PASSWORD",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20))),
                  onFieldSubmitted: (String p) {
                    buttonPressed();
                  },
                ),
```

Then retrieve it using

```
var pass = username.text;
```

Obviously you could use an array of controller and then retrieve them

Comment: Hi thanks, I've just updated the question! do you know how can I do it in that way or similar?

Comment: is DynamicWidget something you have control over? Because maybe you could pass a new optional controller parameter to that widget!

For the array of textediting controller you could see some info here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58433524/flutter-array-of-texteditingcontroller

Comment: I gonna edit the post again and paste the full code

Comment: DynamicWidget is a stateless widget, so your controllers keep being initializated every time you call setstate on the parent.
If you set DynamicWidget as statefull, even if you call setstate on the parent, the controller will not be resetted!

Comment: Yeah I changed that but what I need is when the parent uses setstate, each time adds a new element to array, in this case a new DynamicWidget with the data in the inputs. I know is a bit complex and difficult to implement. I am trying now to do it with BLoC pattern and is quite difficult as well.

Answer (score 0):

my tricky is make one `TextField` have properties `autofocus: true,` with `onChange(lock) => lock = true`

then when initState is run or widget is build , we set data with `if (lock == false)` **setALLYourDataInController**

code :

```
bool lock = false;

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
...
if (lock == false) {
      firstNameController.text = detail?.firstName.toString() ?? '';
}
...
    }
```

my `TextField`

```
TextField(
              autofocus: true,
              style: kTextFieldTextStyle,
              decoration: kInputDecoration.copyWith(
                hintText: 'Yogithesymbian',
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person_add),
                suffixIcon: firstNameController.text.isNotEmpty
                    ? IconButton(
                        onPressed: firstNameController.clear,
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.clear,
                          color: kPrimaryColorLight,
                        ),
                      )
                    : null,
              ),
              onChanged: (unuse) {
                lock = true; // here is logic
                // set.updatePounds(int.parse(pounds));
              },
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
              controller: firstNameController,
            ),
```