# Flutter: Array of AnimationController

Tags: arrays, list, flutter, animationcontroller

How can I create a list of AnimationController?

I found [Flutter: Array of TextEditingController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58433524/flutter-array-of-texteditingcontroller) which shows how to create a list of texteditingcontroller, but with the AnimationController there's a required vsync and I haven't figured out how to get that to work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution.  I was trying to initialize both the controller and list in initState.  I had to initialize the controller outside of initState and it worked:

```
_controller = List.generate(3, (i) => AnimationController(
    vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 2500)));
```